# How do i access input data of a form from Laravel server

Tags: laravel

[image][image]enter image description here[image][image][image]below is the form

```
                  <form method="post" style="display: none;" encType="multipart/form-data" class="landLords1" name="addACourse" action="{{URL::to('/addACourse')}}">
                       {{ csrf_field() }}
                       <input type="text" placeholder="Course Title" name="title"><br>
                       <select name="duration" id="duration">
                           <option value="1 weeks">1 week</option>
                           <option value="2 weeks">2 weeks</option>
                           <option value="3 weeks">3 weeks</option>
                           <option value="4 weeks">4 weeks</option>
                           <option value="5 weeks">5 weeks</option>
                           <option value="6 weeks">6 weeks</option>
                           <option value="7 weeks">7 weeks</option>
                           <option value="3 months">3 months</option>
                           <option value="4 months">6 months</option>
                           <option value="5 months">5 months</option>
                           <option value="6 months">6 months</option>
                           <option value="7 months">7 months</option>
                           <option value="8 months">8 months</option>
                           <option value="9 months">9 months</option>
                           <option value="10 months">10 months</option>
                           <option value="11 month">11 months</option>
                           <option value="1 year">1 year</option>
                       </select><br>
                       <input type="text" placeholder="price" name="price"><br>
                       <input type="text" placeholder="Course Code e.g(ECN 504)" name="coursecode"><br>
                       <input type="text" name="author" placeholder="Authors names"><br>
                       <input type="file" name="picture" placeholder="select picture"><br>
                       <textarea name="desscription" id="textArea" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="write a detail descripton of the content of the course you are creating, write a summary of the course. this content will be displayed went users click on the course"></textarea><br>
                       <button>submit</button><br>
                    </form>
```

Below is the javascript code

```
           function addACourse(param){
                 //event.preventDefault();
                 console.log(param);
                 const theToken = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
                 //const theForm = document.getElementsByClassName('landLords1')[0];
                 var formData = new FormData(param);
                     formData.append('vin', 'value');
                 var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                       xhttp.open('POST', '/addACourse', true);
                       xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                                console.log(this.responseText);
                                return;
                                const data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                                      console.log(data);
                                      // use data here!
                            }
                       }

                       xhttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', theToken);
                       xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", 'XMLHttpRequest');
                       xhttp.setRequestHeader("processData", 'false');
                       xhttp.setRequestHeader('cache', 'false');
                       //xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                       xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(formData));

         }

         const theForm = document.getElementsByClassName('landLords1')[0];
         theForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                addACourse(this);
                return;
         }, false);
```

This is my laravel controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DB;
use Storage;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;

class AddACourseController extends BaseController
{
public function addACourse(Request $request){

    $value = $request->input('coursetitle');
    return response()->json(array('data' => $value), 200);
}
}
```

My intension is not to use Jquery to submit the form. I want to submit the form using xmlHttpRequest(). I keep getting null on the server each time I try to submit the form, have tried using both

```
$theData = $request->input('coursetitile');
$data = $request->coursetitle;
return response()->json(array('data' => $data, 'theData'  => $theData),200);
//note coursetitle is one of the imput field.
```

I keep getting null, please how do i resolve this.
please I do not want any answer that uses JQuery to resolve this.
I want answer in vanila javascript alone.

Comment: please I need someone to help resolve this

Comment: have you `dd($request->all())` in your controller

Comment: yes. the output was an a text containing all the input field plus a gibberish data

Comment: can you share screen shot

Comment: open debug bar and click on network select request which is sent and click on preview and then send screenshot of that

Comment: I did $request->all();

Comment: and can you share what is in request header in browser debug bar network section @Olatunji Odelade

Comment: can you show header in the network in browser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180756/discussion-between-shaielndra-gupta-and-olatunji-odelade).

Comment: before `xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(formData));` you should `console.log(formData)` and tell me what it shows to you

Comment: You could try setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header and/or the `withCredentials` property on your `XMLHttpRequest`. It's possible that your csrf token is being ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell from your screenshots and code, you're not actually submitting any data to the server.

Your first screenshot talks about the Request Payload right at the very bottom. It's slightly cut off, but it looks like you are submitting an empty form. This means that your javascript is not finding any form data to send.

Going backwards through this, you are calling *addACourse* from your eventlistener with an anonymous function (a closure).

```
theForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    addACourse(this);
    return;
}, false);
```

When you are referring to *this* in a closure, you are referring to the closure itself, and not the caller. Naturally, the closure has no form, therefore you have no form data.

Instead (this is untested), try to pass a reference to the form to your *addACourse* function. You may need to tweak it a little to get the form data.

```
theForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    addACourse(theForm);
    return;
}, false);
```

Comment: @json eventually what solve this was resetting the contentType of the requestHeader to false and then sending it to the server with stringifing it

Answer (score 0):

Jason, if your answer were the solution, why would this line:

```
formData.append('vin', 'value');
```

Located within his AddAClass() function not appear within the Request body sent to the server?

Comment: This app will not allow me to comment on other answers (only my own)

Answer (score 0):

After wasting a lot of time trying hard to get this done on time, I found out eventually that in setting the attributes of the requestHeader, 'contentType' should be used and not 'content-Type', ie.
I changed

```
xhttp.setRequestHeader('content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
```

to

```
xhttp.setRequestHeader('contentType', 'multipart/form-data');
```

this entirely solved the issue, the payload was loaded properly with the formData object and laravel was able to access the input fields.
Thanks a lot guys for making attempts to help me out, stackoverflow is a great community.